# JQuery toggle not working while using a single button to hide and show the content

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery in my rails app. Where I am trying to toggle the comments in my blog app. The toggle should be through the same button and should change text from "Hide Comments" to "Show Comments" once it hides the comment.

In application.js I have code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#togButton').click(function(){
    $('.comment').toggle();
    if $('#togButton').text() == 'Hide Comments' {
        $('#togButton').text('Show Comments');
    } else {
        $('#togButton').text('Hide Comments');
    }
  });
});
```

In my view file, I have THE CONTENT TO HIDE HERE

```
<p class="comment">
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p class="comment">
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>

<p class="comment">
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>

and THE BUTTON IS HERE

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>




<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @article.comments %>
<button id="togButton">Hide Comments</button> 
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

When I am pressing the Hide Comment. Nothing is Happening. Also, tell me How do I debug Jquery codes

Comment: Are you trying to toggle the visibility of the comments section?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: Can you please put the code in the same file and then check your click action by putting **alert()** method in it or also you can use **debugger** for debugging your javascript code.

Comment: Thanks for quick response guys.. see the code i found out later that 'if' statement in not enclosed in parenthesis, that was causing the problem